# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items' xx

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make a basic ShoppingCart class. I want to write the total price of the added products to the screen but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20220516/21/45/hackerrank-bc7f3477ddb14067c979abbf6076d52d/code/Solution.py", line 51, in <module>
    item = Item(name, int(price))
  File "/tmp/submission/20220516/21/45/hackerrank-bc7f3477ddb14067c979abbf6076d52d/code/Solution.py", line 16, in __init__
    ShoppingCart.total(self.price)
  File "/tmp/submission/20220516/21/45/hackerrank-bc7f3477ddb14067c979abbf6076d52d/code/Solution.py", line 34, in total
    for i in self.items:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

```
    #!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



class Item:
    def __init__(self,name:str,price:int):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        
        ShoppingCart.total(self.price)
    
    
  
class ShoppingCart():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        
        
        
    def add(self,item):
        
        self.items.append(item)
    
    def total(self):
        x = 0
        
        for i in self.items:
            x+= i.price
        
        return x
        
    def __len__(self):

        return (len(self.items))
        
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())
    items = []
    for _ in range(n):
        name, price = input().split()
        item = Item(name, int(price))
        items.append(item)

    cart = ShoppingCart()

    q = int(input())
    for _ in range(q):
        line = input().split()
        command, params = line[0], line[1:]
        if command == "len":
            fptr.write(str(len(cart)) + "\n")
        elif command == "total":
            fptr.write(str(cart.total()) + "\n")
        elif command == "add":
            name = params[0]
            item = next(item for item in items if item.name == name)
            cart.add(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown command %s" % command)
            
    fptr.close()
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Most of the code you've posted is irrelevant to the error you're seeing. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72265990/edit) the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reason you get this error.  Fixing it will require a rethink on your part.

You are calling:

```
        ShoppingCart.total(self.price)
```

You are calling it as if it were a class method.  There is no object here, so there is no automatic "self" being provided.  That means that the `total` function is going to receive the integer value in `self.price` where it expects to see `self`.  When it calls `self.items`, `self` is an integer, and results in the error.

`total` is not a class method, so you should not be calling it with `ShoppingCart.total`.  More than that, however, `Item`s should not be talking to the shopping cart at all.  The `ShoppingCart` holds `Item`s.  The items do not need to know they are in a shopping cart at all.  So, just delete that line and you can move on to the next problem.